# one to many relation how to create a new row with mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench

i'm really new to mysql triggers so...i have 3 tables: a,b and c. table a is related with table b with a one to many relaion and table c is the table that get the triggered infromation from the 2 other tables.

```
 table a
 ------------------
  id     |    name
   1     |    Juan 
   2     |    Pete
   3     |    David

 table b
 ----------------------
  id  |  name   | table_a_id
   1  |  Dog    |     1
   2  |  Cat    |     2
```

Table C gets the information from Table A with a "**after insert on A
for each row insert into C** "also gets information From table B with a "**after insert on B for each row update C**".

```
 table c
----------------------
id | name a | name b | table_a_id |table_b_id
 1 |  juan  |   Dog  |      1     |      1
 2 |  Pete  |   Cat  |      2     |      2
```

The problem occurs when Pete wants to have Cat and Dog at the same time because it will just update Pete's information. What i want is a way in which i can have a new row with all the information.

```
      table c
     -------------------------------------------
    id | name a | name b | table_a_id |table_b_id
     1 |  juan  |   Dog  |      1     |      1
     2 |  Pete  |   Cat  |      2     |      2
---->3 |  Pete  |   Dog  |      2     |      1
```

This 3rd row from table C wont be created it will just update row 2 from table C. Please tell e if i was clear enough.

Comment: Why you need in 3rd table? You can freely and easily obtain this data from first 2 tables using one simple query when needed...

Comment: cause m using metabase to make some graphs and you cannot do inner joins on it

Comment: *cannot do inner joins on it* Use cartesian + condition, what a problem? Or your metabase allow single-table selections only?

Comment: yup, single tables selections only. Thats why im in this trouble now

Comment: Does `INSERT .. ODKU` and/or `REPLACE` are available?

Comment: the only things available are simple queries, select distinc, group by asc, desc, where conditions etc..

Comment: ... and triggers. Strange... Please specify your metabase and give a link to its documentation.

Comment: triggers are made inside the mysql database, metabase is used just to graph data from database using queries.

Comment: Create multi-table view via MySQL, and use it as it is a table.